# Issue with creating new xml files

Tags: android, eclipse, htc-android

I'm trying to create a new xml file in `/res/drawable` (developing for android in eclipse)

the message i get is ;

> Multiple annotations found at this
>   line:
>     - Premature end of file.
>     - error: Error parsing XML: no       element found

When I'm in the right folder i press New>File , then I name it to `ic_tab_artists.xml`, and right after i get the message ^

So, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something that makes sense inside the file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true">

    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />    
</selector>
```